# What to call an object that acts like an enter-only-once gate?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, naming

What would you call a stateful function/object `x() -> bool` with the following behavior: on the first call it returns `TRUE`, on all consecutive calls it returns `FALSE`. Maybe there is a pattern name already for such functionality?

Comment: In most javascript library (rambda, lodash, ...) this functions are called `once`.

Comment: It's the simplest version of a [Circuit Breaker](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html), where the breaker trips automatically after one invocation and never resets.

Answer (score 1):

The closest concept is the *read-once object* pattern from the [Secure by Design](https://www.manning.com/books/secure-by-design) book. Look at the paragraph below describing the object that allows to request the password only once.

---

A read-once object is, as the name implies, an object designed to be read once. This object
usually represents a value or concept in your domain that’s considered to be sensitive
(for example, passport numbers, credit card numbers, or passwords). The main purpose
of the read-once object is to facilitate detection of unintentional use of the data
it encapsulates.

```java
public final class SensitiveValue {
    private transient final AtomicReference<String> value;

    public SensitiveValue(final String value) {
        validate(value);
        this.value = new AtomicReference<>(value);
    }

    public String value() {
        return notNull(value.getAndSet(null),
            "Sensitive value has already been consumed");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SensitiveValue{value=*****}";
    }
}
```

---

I don't know the full context of your problem but the book suggests to use the *read-once object* pattern in favor of security perspective. [@jaco0646](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371329/jaco0646) also pointed out in the comments that the concept is similar to the [circuit breaker](https://microservices.io/patterns/reliability/circuit-breaker.html) pattern. Though it doesn't force for the object to always return the same value on consecutive calls. Instead, it temporary makes to obtain the stub value to give the external service some time to recover.